# Selecting one of all possible pairs and deleting ones not selected

Tags: netlogo

I will first try to indicate what I am trying to do. Then I will provide code that is not working, code I see two problems with but do not know how to fix. (There may be other problems with the code as well).

I had a file of 200 observations. I created a file that contains all possible combinations of two observations (minus each pair of an observation with itself). In the file there are two cases for each combination, one in which case A is "ego" and case B is "alter", and another where case B is "ego" and case A  is "alter". For ease of discussion, I refer to both CaseAB and CaseBA as "pairs". I read this paired file into netlogo.

Each pair has two sets of variables: egoID egovar1 egovar2 egovar3 alterID altervar1 altervar2 altervar3. Ego* variables refer to characteristics of ego. Alter* variables refer to characteristics of alter. Each pair has a joint variable called "worth".

This file means that each individual appears as ego 199 times and as alter 199 times. One wrinkle is each ego has one of the variables that it prioritizes. So, each ego ignores most of the 199 pairs in which it is ego. Two more wrinkles here. First, there is one "priority rule" that lets an ego consider all remaining pairs. That is the rule of using egovar1.

A second wrinkle is that I removed all pairs that an ego cannot consider given its prioritization (I know this means egovar1 priorities are affected. That's substantively okay). But note: egoA can remove pair egoA,alterB as not worth considering, but alterB, when it is ego, can consider egoB,alterA, which is the same pair, just reversed roles.)

Sorry for the long set-up, but I wanted to be clear of the constraints. I want to do the following:

1. Randomly select an ego,
2. Have ego select the pair that, given its set of pairs that meet its prioritization, has the maximum worth
3. Have ego set paired = 1 for that pair (so this ego & alter are no longer available for consideration in any other pairs with egos or alters in action 2 above)
4. Kill all other pairs where egoID equals the ego's id
5. Kill all other pairs where egoID equals the alter's id
6. Kill all other pairs where alterID equals the ego's id
7. Kill all other pairs where alterID equals the alter's id

In the relevant code:

A. origin is defined elsewhere, to make completed pairs move to the center

B. idx is ego's id

C. idx2 is alter's id

D. myprioritygroup is meant to define the set of pairs the ego considers
  NOTE: I've tried a few ways of doing this. This version is not working.

E. I do not know how to "kill" all pairs with ego & alter ids as ego or alter

Here is the snippet of relevant (failing) code:

```
   to matchem

  ask pairs with [paired = 0]
      [
        ifelse 
        (priority = egovar1)
        [ask max-one-of pairs [pairworth]
         [ set paired 1
         move-to origin
         ask other pairs with [idx = idx] [set paired 9]
         ask other pairs with [idx2 = idx2] [set paired 9]
         ask other pairs with [idx = idx2] [set paired 9]
         ask other pairs with [idx2 = idx] [set paired 9]
         ask other pairs with [paired = 9] [die]
          ]
        ]
        [ask max-one-of pairs with [priority = myprioritygroup] [pairutil]
         [set paired 1
         move-to origin
         ask other pairs with [idx = idx] [set paired 9]
         ask other pairs with [idx2 = idx2] [set paired 9]
         ask other pairs with [idx = idx2] [set paired 9]
         ask other pairs with [idx2 = idx] [set paired 9]
         ask other pairs with [paired = 9] [die]
        ]
        ]
   ]

  tick
```

**EDIT** (after comment): In response to JenB, and based on work conducted in the last 24 hours, I have new code (should I delete the above?) and can offer a more focused question. Here is the newer code:

```
to matchem1
  ask pairs with [priorityx >= 4] [die]
  (ifelse priorityx = 3 and paired = 0
        [ask max-one-of pairs [var2]
         [ set paired 1
         setxy 0 0
           set idegotodelete idx
           set idaltertodelete idx2
         ask other pairs with [idx = idegotodelete and paired != 1] [die]
         ask other pairs with [idx2 = idegotodelete and paired != 1] [die]
         ask other pairs with [idx = idaltertodelete and paired != 1] [die]
         ask other pairs with [idx2 = idaltertodelete and paired != 1] [die]
          ]
        ]
        priorityx = 1 and paired = 0
       [ask max-one-of mysupportlevelgroup [pairutil]
         [set paired 1
         setxy 0 0
           set idegotodelete idx
           set idaltertodelete idx2
         ask other pairs with [idx = idegotodelete and paired != 1] [die]
         ask other pairs with [idx2 = idegotodelete and paired != 1] [die]
         ask other pairs with [idx = idaltertodelete and paired != 1] [die]
         ask other pairs with [idx2 = idaltertodelete and paired != 1] [die]
        ]
        ])
end
```

In this version the first line successfully kills off most pairs so I can work with only two priorities, to simplify debugging. That's the end of success. To answer JenB, in this case the command file does not work in the following sense: I cannot get it to do anything in this block except the first line. It sets up the pairs, all pairs take places on the grid, then... nothing. For 18 hours. If I "show count pairs" there is no answer. So, as you can imagine, it is difficult to identify just where the problem is when there is almost no information. Still, I think two (of perhaps several) problems would be solved with answers to these two questions:

1. How do I a)identify a pair in an ifelse statement, b)get that pair to modify its values on a variable, and c)get that pair to kill selected other pairs.
2. How do I make a series of ifelse statements that randomly call interwoven subsets of pairs (i.e., a pair can be in multiple subsets) such that a pair identified in question 1 above does the murderous actions in 1) above for all pairs, not just those in the specific subset selected.

Comment: You haven't actually said what's wrong - 'not working' is not a description. Is it generating an error? Is it doing the wrong thing - if so, what did you expect and what did it do? You have 7 steps, which step is not working and why do we need to know about the other 6? Please be specific about your problem.

Comment: It's up to you to decide if the older version of your code is no more relevant to the issue(s), in which case you should indeed delete it (post is already raher way too long and unfocused).